# Do xml selectors states 'AND' between one another?

Tags: android, xml

Imagine I had an xml resource like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/one"
            android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
  </selector>
```

Would the first `drawable` be shown when **any** of the two states is reached or when **both** states are? I couldn't find the answer in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), or anywhere in that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item will be drawn when both conditions are met which allows you do have multiple states for "pressed & focused", "pressed" and "focused".

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/one"
            android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/two"
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/three"
            android:state_focused="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
  </selector>
```

So if you set the background of a View to this selector, the default will be `transparent`. When you focus on the View, then `drawable/three` will be drawn.  If you unfocus and the user presses on it, `drawable/two` will be drawn.  If you refocus while the user presses on it, `drawable/one` will be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

A View's state must match all of the criteria defined in a selector state.

The first item in your drawable requires a View to be both pressed and focused.